# Importing Doodle library in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to learn Scala and I've started reading *Creative Scala* by Gurnell and Welsh. In chapter 3, you're supposed to work with Doodle but it's not explained how to import it. What I have is an IntelliJ project with the Scala plugin and SBT. I've added the following line to build.sbt:

`libraryDependencies += "org.creativescala" %% "doodle" % "0.9.25"`.

"sbt: org.creativescala:doodle_2.13:0.9.25.jar" appears under "External Libraries" on the left side of the window but the IDE doesn't recognize "doodle" in `import doodle.core._`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to reload / re-import / refresh the project somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late reply so you may have found your answer already, but Doodle doesn't work that well with IntelliJ.

The documentation suggests using any test editor + Metals. The metals website has instructions on how to use it with various editors.

I've been using it with Visual Studio code: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode